# Is there a turtle function or other Haskell abstraction for joining commands using .&&

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I have the following piece of code:

```hs
foldM (\exitCode args -> pure exitCode .&&. someCmdWith args) ExitSuccess argss
```

Which uses [`turtle`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.13/turtle-1.5.15/)'s  [`(.&&.)`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.13/turtle-1.5.15/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:.-38--38-.) operator.

Is there a better abstraction I could use to apply `.&&.` to the results of applying `someCmdWith` to `argss`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
runCmds argss = foldr (.&&.) (pure ExitSuccess) (fmap someCmdWith argss)
```

If you want to write it even shorter, I believe this would also work:

```
runCmds = foldr (.&&.) (pure ExitSuccess) . fmap someCmdWith
```

Answer (score 2):

`(.&&.)` looks associative and there seems to be a neutral element (`pure ExitSuccess`) so let's define a `Monoid`:

```
newtype UntilFailure = UntilFailure { runUntilFailure :: IO ExitCode }

instance Monoid UntilFailure where
     mappend (UntilFailure a1) (UntilFailure a2) =  UntilfFailure (a1 .&&. a2)
     mempty = UntilFailure (pure ExitSuccess)
```

Then we can write stuff like:

```
runUntilFailure . foldMap UntilFailure $ someCmdWith <$> argss
```

The nice thing about defining a `Monoid` is that we don't have to remember which is the neutral element every time we fold a list of items, as it comes "baked in the type", so to speak.

I don't think one can define a monoid out of [`(.||.)`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.13/turtle-1.5.15/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:.-38--38-.) however, because the neutral element would have to somehow preserve the exit code of the previous command. One could still define a `Semigroup`, though.